# problem to send email from site: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I have problem with sending email by SMTP service
this is code in myfile.aspx :

> <%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>

> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>

```
<script runat="server"> 
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Subject As String = "This is test mail with html web page"
        Dim ToEmail As String = "toemail@sample.com"
        Dim SMTPUser As String = "info@mysite.com"
        Dim SMTPPassword As String = "mysamplepass"
        Dim e_mail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        e_mail = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress(SMTPUser)
        e_mail.To.Add(ToEmail)
        e_mail.Subject = "testEmail"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        e_mail.Body = "<p>send test message to email</p>"
        e_mail.Priority = Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
        Dim smtp_server As New SmtpClient
        smtp_server.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp_server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(SMTPUser, SMTPPassword)
        smtp_server.Port = 587 'try with 465 and 25
        smtp_server.EnableSsl = True
        smtp_server.Host = "mail.mysite.com"
        Try
            smtp_server.Send(e_mail)
        Catch ex As SmtpFailedRecipientsException
            For i = 0 To ex.InnerExceptions.Length Step 1
                Dim status As SmtpStatusCode = ex.InnerExceptions(i).StatusCode
                If status = SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy Or status = SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable Then
                    Response.Write("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.")
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                    smtp_server.Send(e_mail)
                Else

                    Response.Write("Failed to deliver message to " & i & " error::: " & ex.InnerExceptions(i).FailedRecipient")
                End If
            Next i

        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}" & ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
</script>
```

This is the error:

Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush() at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn) at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at ASP.path_myfile_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in path\myfile.aspx:line 25

Comment: What port does your SMTP server listen at? Does your SMTP server use TLS or SSL?

Comment: Which line is line 25?

Comment: @mason the host information is:

Supported incoming mail protocols
POP3, POP3 over SSL/TLS, IMAP, IMAP over SSL/TLS

Supported outgoing mail protocols
SMTP

To send messages via SMTP securely, use port 465.

Comment: @wazz >> smtp_server.Send(e_mail)

Comment: @mason ssl=true

Comment: There are lots of search results for `System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.` What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to use SSL, then why is your code showing port 587 when the mail server documentation says to use 465 for secure mail?

Comment: @mason I tried with ports 465, 587 and 25 but they all show the same results

Comment: @mason when I tried with port 465, this is error: Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at ASP.path_myfile_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in path/myfile.aspx:line 25